# Appending a string with string in ios

Tags: iphone

I am in a problem with some text sharing to evernote,sharing evernote is success,but here is my current situation with code. I have a `UITableView` which has some text and title for that corresponding text. When the share button is clicked it will share the text onebyone to evernote website, but the title remains static. There I get the first title name along with diffrent text. My code for this is in my tableview in `rowAtIndexPath`

```
NSMutableString *strr=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[appDelegate.indexArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
cell.textLabel.text =strr ;
cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.indexArray objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0]; 
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];


[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:row]];
//cell.detailTextLabel.text =notes;
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0]; 
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

`appDelegate.indexArray` is the title content for each cell and `appDelegate.notesArray`  has the textnote for the corresponding titles.

In shareButton click:

```
 NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"NOTES:"]; 
 for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.notesArray count]; i++) { 
        NSString * aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]] ;
        NSString * ENML= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note>%@",aString];

    ENML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ENML, @"</en-note>"];
    NSLog(@"%@", ENML);

    // Adding the content & resources to the note
    [note setContent:ENML];
```

This will give the one by one upload of notetext.but for title I include this code

```
NSMutableString *strtitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"myBibleApp"]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.indexArray count];i++ ) { 
        NSString * aStringtitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[appDelegate.indexArray objectAtIndex:i]] ;
       /* NSString *ENMLtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", aStringtitle];
        NSLog(@"%@", ENMLtitle);*/

    note.title = aStringtitle;
```

But here is my problem it uplode the title and text in double. That means, I have one text with title. When I click the sharebutton it uploads two times.1=2,2=4,3=6 like that.
Nut only addding the title I get this problem. If I put the title static,note.title =@"statictitle". It will not repeat the upload. How can I append the string in correct way? 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

Two things I noted:

The use of NSMutableString is not needed. Just write for the first case

```
cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.indexArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

For the 2 other cases you don't use the string at all (or it's not shown in your code).

In the for-loops, you're always overwriting aString and aStringtitle, and that even with a new alloc. Appending goes like this:

```
NSString *aString = @"";
for ...
  aString = [aString stringByAppendingString:[appDelegate.indexArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

or

```
    aString = [aString stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", [appDelegate.indexArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Check the NSString Class Reference for details.

Comment: haii,thaks for the reply,i remove the first one from the code.i notice that after i post this question.and in the case of appDelegate.notearray,it works perfect.but when i add appDelegate.indexArray it duplicates.any solution?

Comment: Add a `NSLog(@"appDelegate.indexArray %@", [appDelegate.indexArray description]);` to see the content. Maybe it contains duplicates already.

Comment: I have created app delegate global string and append strings in that string in multiple classes as my appplication control moves but i m getting only last appended string ? 
Please suugest